# c# Serial port losing trailing character

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a Modbus interface in my project. I have two serial ports on my PC, one on board and one USB to serial.
If I use the on board serial port i always miss the last character of the return string, if i use the USB to serial port I always get the whole return string.

//ONBOARD--------

> TX: 01 03 02 00 00 12 C4 7F
>   RX: 01 03 24 00 00 00 64 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 00 06 FA 02 D0 D9 54 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 0C 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 00 00 00 C6

//USB to SERIAL--------------

> TX: 01 03 02 00 00 12 C4 7F
>   RX: 01 03 24 00 00 00 64 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 00 06 FA 02 D0 D9 54 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 0C 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 00 00 00 C6 E9

if am using the DataReceivedHandler event:

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int rxcnt = 0;
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;

    for (rxcnt = 0; rxcnt < _serialPort.BytesToRead; rxcnt++)
    {
        rx_buffer[rx_buffer_len++] = (Byte)_serialPort.ReadByte();
    }
}
```

Same code running on 2 different ports but different results, any ideas?
Regards
Richard

Something I just found... I flush the in & out buffers before I transmit the Modbus message. 
If i don't flush the rx_buffer i see the missing character at the start of the next received packet:
TX: 01 03 02 00 00 12 C4 7F 
RX: 01 03 24 00 00 00 64 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 00 06 FA 02 D0 D9 54 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 0C 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 00 00 00 C6

TX: 01 03 02 00 00 12 C4 7F 
RX: **E9** 01 03 24 00 00 00 64 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 00 06 FA 02 D0 D9 54 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 0C 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 00 00 00 C6

I don't understand why this character comes through with the next message because there is a 1000mS delay between the two messages

_serialPort = new SerialPort();

```
        _serialPort.PortName = ports.ElementAt(0);
        _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        _serialPort.ReadBufferSize = 250;
        _serialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;


        _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        try
        {
            _serialPort.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            this.Close();
        }
```

[image: Device manager port setup]}

Comment: Different port configuration setting maybe? Do both the on-board and USB to serial ports have the same port settings in your device manager?

Comment: Who made your USB->Serial converter

Comment: @SpaceghostAli I checked under the port settings and the advanced settings in device manager and they are both setup the same

Comment: @BugFinder The USB-Serial is branded Mecer (A South African company) but uses the Prolific USB->Serial driver

Comment: @BugFinder I do not understand what you mean by "pants.. utter and utter pants". Also if I use Docklight (a very good serial port program) I receive all the characters through the prolific serial port

Comment: From your update it looks like this might be an issue with the receive buffers on the on-board port, not your code. If you know your message length before hand or can read it from the message though it should be easy to continue reading and complete the message when the rest of it comes through

Comment: Can you shorten the responses to test it out?

Comment: Instead of the loop, do you get anything different if you just call `sp.ReadExisting()`?

Comment: @SpaceghostAli I have shortened the packet to 9 bytes and i have the same issue of only receiving 8 bytes, always 1 short. If i wait 10 seconds between transmit and when i check the received buffer i don't ever get the missing character. I only ever get it when the next command comes through

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I changed to sp.ReadExisting and still the same

Comment: Could you post the code that initializes the SerialPort and the port settings from the device manager?

Comment: @Richard if you google usb to serial prolific comes up as having tons of compatibility issues with things.

Comment: @BugFinder My apologies for confusing things yesterday, long day. Prolific USB to Serial works 100%, generic serial port on the motherboard = not working properly.

Comment: @SpaceghostAli I have added my device manager settings plus my program port initialization

Comment: @Richard Oddly, I actually read it as the USB has 1 more byte than the internal, and wondered if it was actually adding one...

Comment: @BugFinder No, the internal is one byte short every time. the USB is correct